# Improper enablement of Menu Items

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I'm working in Product based on Eclipse Luna.
Lets say, I have a perspective named 'XYZ'.
When my product is opened and I open the XYZ perspective, I add 3 new Menu Items to the Workbench window's ToolBar.
The 3 items are 'Login', 'Logout' and 'Search'.
    These Menu contributions are backed by separate 'Command' and 'Handler', individually. (Each Menu item has it's own command and Handler).

    So, When the perspective is loaded, 'Search' and 'Logout' buttons should be disabled. (As the user is not logged in).
    Only the Login button should be enabled.

    Once the user is enabled, 'Search' and 'Logout' buttons should be enabled and 'Login' button should be disabled.
    This is working as expected.

But, when I close my product with 'XYZ' perspective and reopen the product, 'All the 3 icons are enabled'.
    **But shouldn't only `Login` button be enabled?**

There are 3 handlers named `SearchHandler`, `LoginHandler` and `LogoutHandler`.

```
public class LoginHandler extends AbstractHandler { 
    @Override Object execute(final ExecutionEvent event, final IWorkbenchWindow 
      window) throws ExecutionException {
    boolean login;//true when we are able to Login successfully. false otherwise. 
//code to login
    setBaseEnabled(!login);//to enable or disable the logout menu item. 
    } 
}

public class LogoutHandler extends AbstractHandler { 
    @Override Object execute(final ExecutionEvent event, final IWorkbenchWindow 
    window) throws ExecutionException { 

        boolean logOut; //true when we are able to logout successfully. false otherwise. 
//code to logOut 
     setBaseEnabled(!logOut);//to enable or disable the logout menu item. 
    } 
}
```

The above code is working properly when the product is open and user tries to Login and logout alternatively. But, when I close the product with the 'XYZ' perspective open and reopen it, all the 3 icons are enabled

Comment: How can we answer when we don't know exactly how you are controlling what is enabled? Show us some code.

Comment: Thanks Greg for the reply...

Comment: There are 3 handlers named 'SearchHandler', 'LoginHandler' and 'LogoutHandler'.

`code
public class LoginHandler extends AbstractHandler{
@Override
  Object execute(final ExecutionEvent event, final IWorkbenchWindow window) throws ExecutionException {
boolean login;//true when we are able to Login successfully. false otherwise.
//code to login
setBaseEnabled(!login);//to enable or disable the logout menu item.
}
}
`

Comment: `code 
public class LogoutHandler extends AbstractHandler{
@Override
  Object execute(final ExecutionEvent event, final IWorkbenchWindow window) throws ExecutionException {
boolean logOut; //true when we are able to logout successfully. false otherwise.
//code to logOut
setBaseEnabled(!logOut);//to enable or disable the logout menu item.
}
}`

The above code is working properly when the product is open and user tries to Login and logout alternatively.

But, when I close the product with the 'XYZ' perspective open and reopen it, all the 3 icons are enabled.

Comment: Edit your question and put the code there.

Comment: I edited the question and added the code there

Comment: Who's responsible for setting login/logout field values?

Comment: I'm responsible for setting them